# How to convert simple groovy script to lucene expression (or use different method)?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I am using following options for search:

```
scriptSort = 
    _script:
        script: "if(doc['user.roles'].value=='contributor') return 1; else return 2;",
        type: "number",
        order: "asc"

options =
    query: ...
    size: ...
    from: ...
    aggs: ...
    sort: [scriptSort]
```

As you can see I am using `_script` option for sorting results. The problem is that search service that I am using dropped support for `groovy` script language and I have to rewrite this script somehow to something called `Lucene expressions`.

Comment: The big "! IMPORTANT" box on [this page of the Elasticsearch docs](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html) might help, as it provides instructions on how you can continue to use your groovy scripts.

Comment: I can't do that - I am dependant on third party service and I can't configure it - they even said that they are just dropping support for groovy.

Comment: Ah, well in that case, probably the easiest approach is to include if in the query with a high boost, and require the rest of the query.  Something like:  `role:contributor^100 +(some other query terms in here)`

Comment: thanks, could you please write you answer with more details? How query-JSON should look like?

Comment: @femtoRgon it seems that lucene expressions only allow to access numeric fields...

Comment: Can you post the full query you have now? Also, the mapping of that `user.roles` field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an attempt, it should be a pretty general approach though. Use a `function_score` to define your own filters that should be rated differently, based on the value of `user.roles` field. In my example, I think you should replace `"match_all": {}` with whatever you have under `query` (this is the reason why I asked about the full query):

```
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "functions": [
        {
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "user.roles": "contributor"
            }
          },
          "weight": 1
        },
        {
          "filter": {
            "bool": {
              "must_not": [
                {
                  "term": {
                    "user.roles": "contributor"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "weight": 2
        }
      ],
      "boost_mode": "replace"
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "_score": {
        "order": "asc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```